# Testing a method with different case scenarios -

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How could I test a method that does not have any onBlur,onChange,onClick events passing.

This file consists only of cases , break and switches. So I am not really sure how to start for this file.
I already test the base props and it is rendering correctly

Using JEST - ENZYME REACT JS

Another method that calls BuildShapeObj

```
updateFilterList = (filterList) => {
  let localFilters = Object.assign({}, this.state.filters)
  // NOTE: need to change localFilters[props.currentColumnID] with filterList.column
  localFilters[this.props.currentColumnID] = filterList
  if (Object.keys(localFilters[this.props.currentColumnID]).length === 0) {
  delete localFilters[this.props.currentColumnID]
 }
 let updateObj = this.buildShapeObj({switchValue: 'filtering', shapeObjValue: localFilters})
  let updateBoolean = this.shouldUpdateViewXML(localFilters)
  if (updateBoolean) {
  this.props.updateViewXMLValue(updateObj)
}
  this.setState({
  filters: localFilters
})
}
```

Here is just part of the method

```
buildShapeObj = updateObj => {
  let pipe = "shape";
  let shapeObj = {};

  switch (updateObj.type) {
    case "sort":
      shapeObj = {
        0: {
          pipe,
          action: "transform",
          columnName: updateObj.column,
          sort: updateObj.value
        }
      };
      break;
    case "group":
      shapeObj = {
        0: {
          pipe,
          columnName: updateObj.column,
          transformType: "replaceElement",
          matchValue: "resetanalysis"
        },
        1: {
          pipe,
          columnName: updateObj.column,
          transformType: "replaceElement",
          matchValue: "resetallgrouping"
        }
        // ...
      };
      break;
  }
  return shapeObj; //end of method line 350
};
```

If someone could assist on setting up, i would appreciate it
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) so testing it is just a matter of verifying that it returns the correct output based on the input given:

```
describe('buildShapeObj', () => {

  it('should handle sort', () => {
    expect(buildShapeObj({
      type: 'sort',
      column: 'the column',
      value: 'the value'
    })).toEqual({
      0: {
        pipe: 'shape',
        action: 'transform',
        columnName: 'the column',
        sort: 'the value'
      }
    });  // Success!
  });

  it('should handle group', () => {
    expect(buildShapeObj({
      type: 'group',
      column: 'the column'
    })).toEqual({
      0: {
        pipe: 'shape',
        columnName: 'the column',
        transformType: "replaceElement",
        matchValue: "resetanalysis"
      },
      1: {
        pipe: 'shape',
        columnName: 'the column',
        transformType: "replaceElement",
        matchValue: "resetallgrouping"
      }
    });  // Success!
  });

});
```

Comment: Brian how would you mock buildShapeObj since its not being defined

Comment: Can you share more about `buildShapeObj` and how you are using it?

Comment: BuildShape is being called in another method as well, just saw this right now

Comment: updateXML = (updateObj) => {

    //this.props.togglepanelLoadSpinner()
    if(updateObj != null){
      let shapeObj = this.buildShapeObj(updateObj)
      this.props.updateViewXMLValue(shapeObj)
    }

Comment: mock function : const buildShapeObj = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({"0": {"action": "transform", "columnName": "the column", "pipe": "shape", "sort": "the value", "transformType": "test type"}});